# Noether's Theorem and conservation of momentum

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, momentum, conservation-laws, coordinate-systems, noethers-theorem

So as we all know for a system that has translational symmetry Noether's Theorem states that momentum is conserved, more precisely the theorem states that the quantity:
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}$$
so the generalized momentum is conserved. Here i have a problem: suppose i want to show  that classical momentum $p=mv$ is conserved in a system with traslational symmetry (also of course potential energy in the Lagrangian does not depend on velocity) I then have:
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}=\frac{\partial K}{\partial \dot{x}}=\frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{x}}\frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2=m\dot{x}.$$
Perfect! But suppose that i want to use a parametrization for my system, so:
$$x(t)=\Gamma(q(t))$$
as we usually do in Lagrangian Mechanics, then I have that the conserved quantity is still:
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}.$$
In fact Noether's Theorem states that generalised momentum is conserved and this is by definition the generalized momentum. Well then I have:
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}=\frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{q}}\frac{1}{2}m\dot{q}^2|\Gamma ' (q)|^2=m\dot{q}|\Gamma ' (q)|^2=mv|\Gamma ' (q)|.$$
WTF is this?? Furthermore if i choose $\Gamma$ to represent a line with the following parametrization:
$$\Gamma = \begin{bmatrix}kq \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}.$$
I get:
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}=mv|k|$$
so the conserved quantity depends on the parametrization???
Now: I know of course that I made a mistake somewhere; maybe on the content of Noether's Theorem (even if i took the content of said theorem straight from my book of Lagrangian Mechanics) or maybe somewhere else.
My questions are:

1. Why I get this result?
2. How can i show that momentum $p=mv$ is conserved for a symmetrically translational system using Noether's Theorem and using any parametrization $\Gamma$ I want?
3. Is it true that generalised momentum is conserved for any symmetrically translational system?
4. When conservation of generalised momentum implies conservation of classical momentum?

This is my problem; hope you can help me out. Please try to give me a complete answer, this problem is bugging me a lot.

Comment: Is $\Gamma$ a function of $\dot{q} $.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Let us for simplicity consider a 1D system. If the Lagrangian $L(\dot{x},t)$ has a [cyclic variable](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Cyclic_coordinates) $x$, then the action has an infinitesimal translation symmetry $$\delta x~=~\epsilon,$$ and it is well-known that the conserved [Noether charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem)
   $$ Q~=~\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}\tag{1} $$
   is the conjugate momentum.
2. OP considers next a coordinate transformation $$x~=~f(q,t).$$
   Note that $q$ is *not* necessarily a cyclic variable (because $\dot{x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial q}\dot{q}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ may depend on $q$).
   The new symmetry becomes
   $$ \delta q~=~\epsilon Y,$$ where 
   $$Y~=~\frac{\partial q}{\partial x}~=~\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial q}\right)^{-1}$$ is the so-called generator.
   According to Noether's formula, the conserved Noether charge is "momentum times generator":
   $$ Q~=~\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} Y~=~\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}},\tag{2}$$
   which is the same as before because of the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule).